# Decision tree for storing subscription info

Tags: architecture, algorithms, trees

I have a system in which user creates an entity. Now this entity has attributes which are dependent on many external systems. We have all those pipelines in backend which updates these entities when there is any change coming from external systems. 
Now I want to inform user about these updates even when they are not logged into my system - basically a notification service.
User will be subscribing to notification service. For eg : Send me a mail when forecast value is updated for the entities which are created by me and whose status is ready.
I am planning to capture this subscription info and store it in a decision tree.
When an update comes, I will check the tree and find the valid paths in it based on the update.
Now the problem I have is how to reorganise the tree after many users subscribe for notifications? There can be redundant paths which can be optimised.

For eg -: 
user1 : forecast -> createdBy -> status -> email
user2 : forecast -> updatedBy -> status -> email

In this case if I form the tree at status level instead of createdBy/updatedBy, I dont have to traverse one additional path.

There are hundreds of attributes like this and I have to reorganise tree as more and more subscriptions happen.

What would be the best approach for that?Is there any standard algorithm available which can restructure the tree based on data( move more common differentiating attributes close to root node)?

I guess the in one line how do I maintain a decision tree on a stream of data coming in?

TIA